# how to make moving moving graphs that vary in time like a video?

Tags: dataset, visualization, data

like this, like shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2DHpW79w0Y&t=7s).

Answer (score 3):

You can find a list of great library [here](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery).

I would recommend [this one](https://piratepeel.github.io/sportskills.html) but you have to write some css to have that same effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to work with R, you can use the [gganimate](https://github.com/dgrtwo/gganimate) package which works with [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/). It allows you to to save the animation in gif, mp4 or swf afterwards.